# Multiple nouns compounding with the same adjective

Tags: adjectives, punctuation, compound-adjectives

What is the correct way of writing resource-intensive and knowledge-intensive in contracted form?

Would it be:
Resource- and knowledge-intensive?

Or:
Resource and knowledge-intensive?

Comment: Style guides may disagree with each other, but my understanding is adequately expressed [here](http://ontariotraining.net/suspended-hyphen/).  (And it says your first option is correct.)

Comment: This was my gut feeling as well, just wanted to "look up the theory" as I'm non-natively dissertating. This is definitely the way to do it in my native language, it's not always done the same way in English.

Comment: I second Hellion